# why does fclose not set file pointer to NULL?

Tags: c++, pointers, fclose

I was writing a RAII wrapper for FILE *. I noticed that when the FILE * is deleted after close in the destructor it leads to undefined behavior (seg. fault or errors somewhere else). I assumed that the fclose will set the FILE * to NULL, which it did not.

```
class smartFP {
  smartFP (const std::string& name) 
  : fp (fopen(name.c_str(), "r")
  { }

  ~smartFP()
  { 
     if (fp) {
        fclose(fp); 
        // delete(fp); <- This is causing crash
        fp = NULL; <- Is this OK?
     }
  }

private:
   FILE *fp;
};
```

- Why does fclose not set the FILE * to NULL?
- The second question is does fopen allocate memory for fp in the heap or stack? I thought it does on heap and hence wanted to do a delete after fclose, so that the 4 or 8 bytes on heap for fp is de-allocated. But looks like this is not needed.

Comment: Why are you writing a RAII wrapper for `FILE*`?  Why not just use an `fstream` if you're already using C++?

Comment: Upgrading old software is a common reason.  I've done it.  RAII around a FILE* is a much smaller change than replacing it all with streams.

Comment: @Adam - MD is right..replacing exisiting file * with fstream requires more changes, particularly if some of libraries for reading binary files require FILE * to be passed.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Of course `delete fp` is causing a crash. It wasn't allocated with `new`. Only call `delete` on something you got with `new` or with something else that the documentation told you to use it on. The documentation for `fopen` never tells you to use `delete`. All cleanup for files is performed by `fclose`; there's nothing additional you need to do to release file-related resources after you've called it.

Setting `fp = NULL` is fine. It's probably desirable so that future consumers of this "smart file pointer" can check whether the pointer is still valid. (It's more useful from a `reset` method than from the destructor, though; there can't be any future consumers of the pointer class after the destructor has run because the object doesn't exist anymore.) But `fclose` can't do that itself because `fclose` doesn't receive its parameter by reference, and even if it did, it wouldn't be able to invalidate *all* possible copies of the file pointer. Recall that `free` and `delete` don't set their arguments to `NULL`, either.

Comment: I thought about the point you are mentioning regarding setting fp to NULL in destructor. I have an API in the smartFP class that returns FILE * : FILE * get() { return fp; } . The reason for doing this is to do smartFPObj.get() in existing code where FILE * is used. I did not want someone to keep a copy of fp and try to use it after smartFPObj goes out of scope.

Comment: Your `get` method is fine, but your actions in the destructor don't help you at all. If someone calls `get` and stores a copy of the result, they have a *copy* of the result. You can change your `fp` variable to anything you want, but it won't affect the value in the copy. Consider this code: `FILE* fp = fopen(...); FILE* b = fp; fclose(fp); fp = NULL;` Setting `fp` to `NULL` doesn't change `b`. It makes no difference whether `fp` is a member of a class or whether the assignment of `b` comes after a call to some `get` method.

Comment: @srikrish just because you set the pointer member in your class to NULL doesn't mean the copy they saved will be set to NULL. Also Rob, `fclose` is a C function so it would be impossible for it to recieve the `FILE*` by reference (it could take a `FILE**` though of course).

Comment: @Rob - Thanks for clarifying. so when I do fp = fopen(..), is fp allocated on the heap or stack of calling function. Similarly, when you sat "all clean for files done by fclose" does that mean space allocated for private member fp (in stack or heap) is de-allocated or does it happen later.

Comment: @Rob - also does space for FILE * b, which is a copy of fp, get allocated in stack or heap? Is there a copy assignment operator for FILE * which enables this copying.

Comment: The `fp` variable itself is allocated wherever you declared it: If it's a local variable, then it's usually on the stack; if it's a member variable, then it's wherever its associated object is. The `FILE` object that it *points to* is allocated wherever `fopen` decides to allocate it, which is generally none of your concern. There's no special assignment operator for `FILE*`. It's the same plain old assignment operator used for *all* pointer types. There's nothing special about `FILE*`; it's just like any other pointer type, like `int*` and `void*` and `std::string*`.

Answer (score 2):

No, you should not be attempting to `delete` a FILE *.  It is a C library data structure and does not represent a pointer returned from a C++ `new`.

Answer (score 2):

fp isn't allocated by the C runtime, you don't have to free it. fclose doesn't set it to NULL because it CAN'T set it to null (it's a pointer to a FILE structure, not to a FILE *).

How FP is allocated isn't a concern to you, it's not part of your contract with the API, so don't worry about it.

Addenda:

fopen is returning a pointer to a FILE structure. Where and how it gets the memory is not important. It could well be pointing to a static structure in memory. But, basically, you're not responsible for that memory, so you should not mess with it.

Now, the actual fp pointer, you COULD allocate that:

```
FILE **fp = malloc(sizeof(FILE *));
*fp = fopen("file.txt", "r");
...
fclose(*fp);
free(fp);
```

But, obviously, most folks don't do that, they simply use a local stack variable to manage that. Depends on the use case.

Comment: As I explained the reason for deleting fp was to free any space allocated to private member fp by fopen. Since, I thought fclose only frees the space allocated to the file in memory, I wanted to delete fp and free the space. Its still not clear, why is this not required..Is it because fclose does this job.

Answer (score 1):

`fopen` and `fclose` do the neccessary dynamic memory management with `FILE *` elements, so you don't have to call `delete` on them. You can put a NULL value in them if you want, to signal that the file is not assigned, however.

Answer (score 1):

1) fclose *can't* set the FILE* to NULL, because it's parameter is a FILE*, so it recieves the FILE* by value.  Since it's a copy, it cannot alter your pointer, unless the parameter was changed to a FILE*&.
2) In C++, you pretty much never call `delete` unless you called `new`.  If you're doing RAII, you should only assign `new` to smart pointers, and never call `delete` ever.